# Print the list by selecting a value - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

I'm trying to print a list of values ​​with the pressure of one option from a list  .
In the first function, the user selected the value with a click(corresponding to the array with the options to be displayed). So far everything works, the problem is the last function in fact, there is something wrong that I can't understand.

```
var selectedValue = x;

for(i = 0; i < opts[selectedValue].length; i++)
{

var opt = document.createElement('li');
opt = opts[selectedValue][i];

opt.innerHTML = opts[selectedValue][i];
document.body.opn.appendChild(opt);

}
```

SelectedValue is the variable, with this, I get the parameter passed by the other function (the parameter is called x) corresponds to the element clicked by the user in the list.
At this point I create a list of options, which is present in the array. Only I get undefined. Note that "opts" is the array; while "opt" option contains the list you created.

Comment: fiddle please...........

Answer (score 1):

Your variable handling looks a bit quirky: You are assigning the value from the iterated array to `opt` directly after initializing it with your new dom element (?). While the following slightly modified code isn't tested, I'm pretty sure it should lead you into the right direction:

```
var selectedValue = x;

for(i = 0; i < opts[selectedValue].length; i++) {

  var opt = document.createElement('li');
  opt.innerHTML = opts[selectedValue][i];

  document.body.opn.appendChild(opt);
}
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined on:
document.body.opn.appendChild(opt);

Comment: This is related to your dom (HTML). Make sure there's some element like `<select id="opn" ...>`. Even better: Use `document.getElementById('opn')` or `document.getElementByName('opn')`  (latter when using an attribute `name="opn"` for your target element).